# Why would my data extension not be available to select for a population?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, contactbuilder

I am trying to create a population from a data extension that I have setup which will contain all of my contact data.

However, I can't select it from the populations navigation. I can't find on the documentation any word of why it might not be showing up?

Comment: Is it a sendable data extension?

Comment: Yes it is sendable

Comment: Is it in a Shared DE, Is it a Synchronized DE, what does the DE look like? Does it contain a Primary Key? Do you have any data in this DE yet?

Comment: Not Shared, Not Synced, DE has 10 fields, 1 primary key (Email Address), Has 1 record. 

It is currently being used in an attribute group, would that be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure you can not have a DE set in an attribute group but also applied as a population list, you will need to write an SQL Query that replicates the data from the population DE to another DE if you wish to use that DE in both features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what you have told me, it seems you have the desires population data extension already assigned to an Attribute Group. This will no longer be available to you to use unless you remove it from the Attribute Group.

If you require the data extension in your Attribute Group and Population then perform the following

### Solution

1. Keep the existing Data Extension 1 in your attribute group.
2. Copy the Data Extension 1 and Name it Data Extension 2.
3. Write a `SELECT ALL (*)` SQL Query that that populates Data
   Extension 2 from Data Extension 1.
4. Possibly setup a reoccurring automation that populates Data
   Extension 2 so it always contains the latest data depending on your
   scenario.
5. Link Data Extension 2 to a population.

You now have the same data in two seperate data extensions linked in an Attribute Group and a Population.

Comment: Anytime @LukeCrickmore